# How to >=python3.10 on ubuntu 20.04? for Frappe-bench

Tags: python, pip, python-3.10

When I run `bench init frappe-bench`
I get this error:

```
Setting Up Environment
$ python3 -m venv env
$ /home/$USER/bench/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade pip
$ /home/$USER/bench/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet wheel
Getting frappe
$ git clone https://github.com/frappe/frappe.git  --depth 1 --origin upstream
Cloning into 'frappe'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3152, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3152/3152), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2843/2843), done.
remote: Total 3152 (delta 430), reused 1237 (delta 213), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3152/3152), 15.92 MiB | 3.35 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (430/430), done.
Installing frappe
$ /home/$USER/bench/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade -e /home/$USER/bench/frappe-bench/apps/frappe 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pyotp/
ERROR: Package 'frappe' requires a different Python: 3.8.10 not in '>=3.10'
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/home/$USER/bench/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade -e /home/$USER/bench/frappe-bench/apps/frappe ' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/commands/make.py", line 68, in init
    init(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/render.py", line 105, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/system.py", line 79, in init
    get_app(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/app.py", line 444, in get_app
    app.install(verbose=verbose, skip_assets=skip_assets, restart_bench=restart_bench)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/render.py", line 126, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/app.py", line 242, in install
    install_app(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/app.py", line 573, in install_app
    bench.run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/bench.py", line 48, in run
    return exec_cmd(cmd, cwd=cwd or self.cwd, _raise=_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/__init__.py", line 158, in exec_cmd
    raise CommandFailedError from subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)
bench.exceptions.CommandFailedError

ERROR: There was a problem while creating frappe-bench
Do you want to rollback these changes?
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. How do I upgrade / downgrade my python version to suitable version for this and how do I use it?
I have found a ppa repository by deadsnake which provides python 3.10 but when I try to run I get this:

```
Setting Up Environment
$ python3 -m venv env
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.8-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/$USER/bench/frappe-bench/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'python3 -m venv env' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/commands/make.py", line 68, in init
    init(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/render.py", line 105, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/system.py", line 65, in init
    bench.setup.env(python=python)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/render.py", line 126, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/bench.py", line 361, in env
    self.run(f"{venv} env", cwd=self.bench.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/bench.py", line 48, in run
    return exec_cmd(cmd, cwd=cwd or self.cwd, _raise=_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/bench/utils/__init__.py", line 158, in exec_cmd
    raise CommandFailedError from subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)
bench.exceptions.CommandFailedError

ERROR: There was a problem while creating frappe-bench
```

Comment: maybe try `pyenv` ? install it , change python version and start using it. use this if you dont care about the build size . if size is important then download 3.8 and build it from sctrach

Comment: Seems like you are using the latest version of frappe. You can try ubuntu 22.04 for this case as it's highly recommended to use ubuntu 22.04 for frappe version 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04, run:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
sudo apt-get install -y python3.10
```

**Don't change your default Python version!** It could (will) break your entire system. In order to use Python 3.10 for the creation of your virtual environment, run `python3.10 -m venv env` or `virtualenv -p python3.10 env`.

---

As [suggested by sahasrara62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580440/how-to-python3-10-on-ubuntu-20-04-for-frappe-bench#comment133343654_75580440), you can also install pyenv and run:

```bash
pyenv install 3.10.7
```

Comment: I second (or third, I guess) the pyenv recommendation. It's by far the easiest and cleanest way to manage multiple Python versions.

Comment: That's what I use personally, it makes local development sooo simple!

Comment: If you use `pyenv` to manage multiple versions but there is an existing virtualenv in use, is it possible to change that virtualenv to reflect the new version of python or else how does this work?